# Conception of a class with some attributes that will not be logically defined

Tags: c++, class

I have the following class :

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ...
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
}
```

The program will affect a value to some of those variables and others should not be in a valid state for the logic of my program. What is a good way of handling those variables who should not have values? Should I give them a random value (ex 68823773)? This doesn't seem like a clean solution to me.

Comment: If zero isn't used by your program you could use that. Alternatively you could add a bool that states whether or not the correspondding variable is in use.

Comment: One alternative would be to use `boost::optional<int>`.

Comment: You could set the unused variables to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max` or `std::numeric_limits<int>::min`, if you won't use those values for any regular purpose.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a "singular" value (e.g., 0 or -1) to indicate a special value, you could use [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using boost library then you may use std::pair instead of int. Then you may set the bool flag appropriately to determine a valid state.

For example:

```
std::pair<int, bool> value;
```

afterwards when the value has a valid state you may set the flag as below:

```
value.first = <some_value>;
value.second = true;
```

similarly you may reset rest of the members in the class. To check whether the value is in valid state you may use

```
if (value.second)
{
     // true means valid state
     // Do your processing here
}
```

And lastly you may use an array or std::vector of std::pair instead of a series of variables. This way, for some particular condition, you can set the flag for certain index and reset (set false) the flag for all the other index.